# How to handle PDOException in Laravel 5

Tags: php, laravel, pdo, eloquent, laravel-5.1

I've modified Exceptions/Handler.php to:

```
    <?php namespace App\Exceptions;

use Exception;
use Illuminate\Foundation\Exceptions\Handler as ExceptionHandler;
use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\ModelNotFoundException as ModelNotFoundException;
use Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\Exception\NotFoundHttpException;

class Handler extends ExceptionHandler {

    /**
     * A list of the exception types that should not be reported.
     *
     * @var array
     */
    protected $dontReport = [
    'Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\Exception\HttpException'
    ];

    /**
     * Report or log an exception.
     *
     * This is a great spot to send exceptions to Sentry, Bugsnag, etc.
     *
     * @param  \Exception  $e
     * @return void
     */
    public function report(Exception $e)
    {
        return parent::report($e);
    }

    /**
     * Render an exception into an HTTP response.
     *
     * @param  \Illuminate\Http\Request  $request
     * @param  \Exception  $e
     * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response
     */
    public function render($request, Exception $e)
    {

        if($e instanceof NotFoundHttpException)
        {
            return response()->view('errors/404');
        }

        elseif ($e instanceof ErrorException) {
            return response()->view('errors/404');
        }

        elseif ($e instanceof ModelNotFoundException) {
            return response()->view('error_log(message)ors/404');
        }

        elseif($e instanceof PDOException)
        {
            return Redirect::to('install.php');
        }

        elseif($e instanceof QueryException)
        {
            return Redirect::to('install.php');
        }

        else return response()->view('errors/error');


    }
```

trying to redirect to installation whenever application makes PDOException, but I'm just getting general error view (errors/error - from the last line of the code above).

Is there a way to cach specifically PDOException error?

Answer (score 3):

I think I've found the solution:

just put

```
use PDOException;
```

Comment: Or 

try {
} catch (\PDOException $pde) {
}

Answer (score 2):

include 
use PDOException;

```
public function render($request, Exception $e)
    {

        if($e instanceof PDOException)
        {
            return response()->view('errors/404');
        }
```

in Exception/Handler
it worked for me

Answer (score 0):

This is what worked for me in Laravel 5.3 (excerpt of my `Handler.php` file located in `/app/Exceptions/`):

```
public function report(Exception $e)
{

    // Both this, and below, are needed
    if($e instanceof \PDOException) {
        return response()->view('errors/404');
    }

    return parent::report($e);
}

public function render($request, Exception $e)
{

    if($e instanceof \PDOException) {
        // TODO send me an email!
        Session::flash('messageclass', 'danger');
        Session::flash('message', trans('general.pdoexception'));
        return redirect()->back();
    }

    return parent::render($request, $e);
}
```